# Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver slow to launch - why?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've created the simplest-possible NUnit test to initialise a `ChromeDriver`, and it's taking nearly 6 seconds to run.  Most of the time (roughly 4s) is spent with a blank, inactive Chrome window.

[image: Blank Chrome window looks like this]

The ChromeDriver.exe window appears almost instantly.

[image: ChromeDriver.exe window]

My unit test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void Simplest_Possible_Test()
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions { Proxy = null };
    using (new ChromeDriver(options))
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

and I'm using these nuget packages:

```
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="78.0.3904.7000" targetFramework="net47" />
```

My question is:

**Is this slowness expected?  Can I do anything to speed it up?**

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the times.  See how they compare just using the Chrome manually.  Also compare the headers in first request manually against the c# application.  Sometimes slow web requests are due to the  browser view getting refresh.  If you do not need the view the use a httprequest which doesn't have a view.

Comment: It's not even loading a web page.

Comment: Did you open a web page?  It looks like you started the server listening (chrome driver) but did not make any connection to server.  You need to add code where it says // Do Nothing.

Comment: OK.  Not sure you've read the question properly.  I understand how to write Selenium tests.  I made this example to demonstrate that just opening Chrome (and it getting ready to load a web page) takes 6 seconds.

Comment: Do you know what the service is doing?  It may be starting a database and making a connection which takes time.  It also may be going out to a DNS server to verify a credential and may be going to a proxy server and getting a certificate.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and find out where the delays are occurring.

Comment: C# in general is a pretty slow language to automate with. Starting an Appium session on a mobile device takes 45 seconds through C#, which is outrageous. I've find that performance issues are drastically reduced when using Ruby or Python. I think part of this is just the nature of the language that you are using, and there's not much you can do to speed it up other than program in a different language entirely.

Comment: Feels very opinionated to be honest.  When I had a quick try with webdriver.io, I experienced exactly the same perf issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded that this is just how long it takes, and have come up with a way to re-use browser windows.

If you start the `ChromeDriver` via the overload that takes a `ChromeDriverService` and set `EnableVerboseLogging` as follows...

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

... the ChromeDriver window shows verbose info on start-up, including (UNIX-style) timestamps.  I'm now satisfied that the time taken to start is simply normal.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 53677
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1573036834.332][INFO]: [dd05361c2fafe521ffd5fb06e6dbe7a3] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--profile-directory=Default-16031ab478b34fa8838ecc0cb76b2cd1", "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\9f19589865c44ba6aec806fbafc1b561" ]
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--profile-directory=Default-16031ab478b34fa8838ecc0cb76b2cd1", "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\9f19589865c44ba6aec806fbafc1b561" ]
      }
   }
}
[1573036834.335][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1573036834.337][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1573036834.348][INFO]: Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly
[1573036834.348][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\PAUL~1.SUA\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir18488_412533912\internal" --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --profile-directory=Default-16031ab478b34fa8838ecc0cb76b2cd1 --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\9f19589865c44ba6aec806fbafc1b561"

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53680/devtools/browser/bacb830a-c373-460e-83e8-10ab7f05d6ce
[1573036834.744][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:53680/json/version
[1573036835.088][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: {
   "Browser": "Chrome/78.0.3904.70",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "7.8.279.17",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:53680/devtools/browser/bacb830a-c373-460e-83e8-10ab7f05d6ce"
}

[1573036835.104][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:53680/json
[1573036835.122][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: [ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:53680/devtools/page/C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260",
   "id": "C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260",
   "title": "Chrome Automation Extension",
   "type": "background_page",
   "url": "chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:53680/devtools/page/C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:53680/devtools/page/4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
   "id": "4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
   "title": "New Tab",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "chrome://newtab/",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:53680/devtools/page/4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4"
} ]

[1573036835.131][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:53680/json
[1573036835.135][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: [ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:53680/devtools/page/C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260",
   "id": "C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260",
   "title": "Chrome Automation Extension",
   "type": "background_page",
   "url": "chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:53680/devtools/page/C5722CC4576C0C53221985793E2EB260"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:53680/devtools/page/4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
   "id": "4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
   "title": "New Tab",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "chrome://newtab/",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:53680/devtools/page/4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4"
} ]

[1573036835.152][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[1573036837.137][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1573036837.138][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[1573036839.141][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Log.enable (id=1) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.142][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: DOM.getDocument (id=2) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.144][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Target.setAutoAttach (id=3) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "autoAttach": true,
   "waitForDebuggerOnStart": false
}
[1573036839.145][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=4) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.146][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=5) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.146][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Log.enable (id=1) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.147][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: DOM.getDocument (id=2) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "root": {
      "backendNodeId": 2,
      "baseURL": "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html",
      "childNodeCount": 2,
      "children": [ {
         "backendNodeId": 14,
         "localName": "",
         "nodeId": 2,
         "nodeName": "html",
         "nodeType": 10,
         "nodeValue": "",
         "parentId": 1,
         "publicId": "",
         "systemId": ""
      }, {
         "attributes": [ "lang", "en", "class", "inited" ],
         "backendNodeId": 15,
         "childNodeCount": 4,
         "children": [ {
            "backendNodeId": 16,
            "localName": "",
            "nodeId": 4,
            "nodeName": "#comment",
            "nodeType": 8,
            "nodeValue": " TODO(dbeam): dir=\"ltr\"? ",
            "parentId": 3
         }, {
            "backendNodeId": 17,
            "localName": "",
            "nodeId": 5,
            "nodeName": "#comment",
            "nodeType": 8,
            "nodeValue": " Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.\n     Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be\n     found in the LICENSE file. ",
            "parentId": 3
         }, {
            "attributes": [  ],
            "backendNodeId": 18,
            "childNodeCount": 24,
            "localName": "head",
            "nodeId": 6,
            "nodeName": "HEAD",
            "nodeType": 1,
            "nodeValue": "",
            "parentId": 3
         }, {
            "attributes": [ "class", "light-chip win", "style", "background: rgb(255, 255, 255); --logo-color:rgba(238,238,238,1);" ],
            "backendNodeId": 19,
            "childNodeCount": 21,
            "localName": "body",
            "nodeId": 7,
            "nodeName": "BODY",
            "nodeType": 1,
            "nodeValue": "",
            "parentId": 3
         } ],
         "frameId": "4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
         "localName": "html",
         "nodeId": 3,
         "nodeName": "HTML",
         "nodeType": 1,
         "nodeValue": "",
         "parentId": 1
      } ],
      "documentURL": "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html",
      "localName": "",
      "nodeId": 1,
      "nodeName": "#document",
      "nodeType": 9,
      "nodeValue": "",
      "xmlVersion": ""
   }
}
[1573036839.148][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Target.setAutoAttach (id=3) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.148][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=4) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.148][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=5) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.149][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.enable (id=6) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.150][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "04C2466A16DFD233FEE7E6F1A4D5B59C",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 4,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "chrome-search://most-visited"
   }
}
[1573036839.150][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "B6EA84A25C9E0EFFB88946CC7606D044",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 3,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "chrome-search://most-visited"
   }
}
[1573036839.151][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "BA8BAD5C705B50773F7EC3B2596AE5B7",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 2,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "chrome-search://local-ntp"
   }
}
[1573036839.151][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 1,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "chrome-search://local-ntp"
   }
}
[1573036839.151][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.enable (id=6) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.154][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.enable (id=7) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.155][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.enable (id=7) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.155][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.enable (id=8) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.156][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.enable (id=8) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {

}
[1573036839.157][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=9) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "awaitPromise": true,
   "expression": "(function() { // Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.\n// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be\n// found in the LICENSE file.\n\n/**\n * Enum f...",
   "returnByValue": true
}
[1573036839.159][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=9) 4B8C0B4FB68B7222E5E34BB28D75A6E4 {
   "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": {
         "status": 0,
         "value": 1
      }
   }
}
[1573036839.160][INFO]: [dd05361c2fafe521ffd5fb06e6dbe7a3] RESPONSE InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "acceptInsecureCerts": false,
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "browserVersion": "78.0.3904.70",
      "chrome": {
         "chromedriverVersion": "78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800})",
         "userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\9f19589865c44ba6aec806fbafc1b561"
      },
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "debuggerAddress": "localhost:53680"
      },
      "networkConnectionEnabled": false,
      "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
      "platformName": "windows nt",
      "proxy": {

      },
      "setWindowRect": true,
      "strictFileInteractability": false,
      "timeouts": {
         "implicit": 0,
         "pageLoad": 300000,
         "script": 30000
      },
      "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify"
   },
   "sessionId": "dd05361c2fafe521ffd5fb06e6dbe7a3"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using following singleton IWebDriver instance and it only takes couple of seconds to launch.

```
public class UiTest : IDisposable
{
    private IWebDriver driver = null;

    protected IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions{Proxy = null});
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            return _driver;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        driver?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In windows Automatic proxy setup, you can turn off "Automatic detect settings" and see if there is any difference. However, passing null proxy for `ChromeOptions` has the similar effect, I guess.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I do and it works perfectly fine, I usually always dispose the driver and wait helper when the task is complete as there is a known memory leak, but other than that, this works great.

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago, I (and others), built a web bot (don't ask what for :-) ). The target surface was a particular website. For preparations, we replicated as much as possible the target website in an offline LAN environment. Among other tools, we used Selenium to run Chrome, and startup time was ~4-6 seconds, the gig was a Intel Core i5 ~3 GHz 8GB RAM Windows 10 Pro and had another similar computer, a laptop, main difference being it was running Ubuntu 18.04, about same startup time.

C# is not the issue here. After noticing that delay (which is not a big deal, at least for me), considering the offline setting (no requests flying around the Internet), and the different computer builds, I dare to say it's the startup time it takes, that's all, no monkey business.

Faster startup times could be achieved by using a higher end gig with faster memory, faster CPU, faster buses, SSD drives, etc...

Comment: The only way to speed this up is for Chrome to launch faster, or install an SSD drive instead of a magnetic platter hard drive.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I suspected as much. Is good to have another confirmation on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading the **Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver** package resolved it for me

I had updated chrome but not the package and the driver did not complain

chrome version 98
driver version 97

Just wanted to share as it took 5 hours of my life:

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons where Chrome driver is loading very slow. I see you've already found the first one which is the proxy setting. The second one is the bitness of the driver. We've experienced 64-bit version of ChromeDriver was very slow. You can try using other versions of the Chrome Driver.

We are using this version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="2.45.0" />
```

This is not about increasing the load time of the Chrome Driver but how you approach it; When you execute the following piece of code, it opens two executables. Your ChromeDriver.exe and chrome.exe.

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions { Proxy = null };
    using (new ChromeDriver(options))
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
```

If you are don't have different Chrome options for each test, I strongly recommend you to initialize your driver for only once for your all tests and manage your chrome.exe with Quit(), Close() etc. Please see [Setup] or [OnetimeSetup] attributes depending on your version of NUnit. Then your total test run execution time will decrease significantly.

Comment: Version of the ChromeDriver is linked to the version of Chrome -  v45 was released in 2015!

Comment: Good advice to re-use the driver - I'd already reached the same conclusion.  I'd still like to know why the initial start time is so long, though.